# django on_delete = DO_NOTHING

Tags: django, database, model, on-delete

I am developing an app where I need some of the data to be protected even when some models are deleted. I've been reading on the on_delete options, and seems to be a lot of warnings against using on_delete=DO_NOTHING. In my case, I need the results to be maintained even when a yacht or event gets deleted. The basic structure is this;

```
# models.py
class Yacht(models.Model):
     yacht_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Event(models.Model):
     event_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
     yachts = models.ManyToManyField(Yacht, through="Result")
class Result(models.Model):
     yacht = models.ForeignKey(Yacht, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
     event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
     ranking = models.IntegerField(max_lenght=4)
```

For record keeping, I need the results to remain even if a yacht or event is deleted. What is the best approach here? Some thoughts;

1. Create additional Result field (_yacht = models.CharField()) and use a post_save signal to provide a string.
2. Create a separate table to keep records of the events. Table gets created/updated at post_save

Thanks in advance,

J

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the official document at the link below
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Based on this here are some modifications to your code as per your requirements; try it. (If I have understood your requirement correctly)

```
class Result(models.Model):
     yacht = models.ForeignKey(Yacht, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Note: your fields need to be `null=True`; also note "null" is related to database & "blank" is related with your HTML forms

Comment: The only issue with SET_NULL is that it will reference to nothing. I need to preserve a string representation of what was there before. So if a yacht was named Yacht1, once deleted I still want the result to display "Yacht1" at least as a string since the actual object no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you consider a *soft delete* by implementing a *deleted* field in your model(s):

```py
deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

def soft_delete(self):
    self.deleted = True
    self.save()
```

More here:
https://dev.to/bikramjeetsingh/soft-deletes-in-django-a9j